# Can document.referrer be forged?

Tags: javascript, referrer

Situation: We have a widget that we want to allow to be iframed on trusted sites. To mitigate potential Clickjacking attacks, we want to check the referrer when the widget loads against a whitelist of domains. No match = widget disabled.

I know that using Flash you can send arbitrary HTTP requests with any Referer header. Is document.referrer similarly vulnerable?

NOTE: I know users can change settings and other situations can make document.referrer blank. That is fine. The widget always working is less important than that it not work if the website embedding it is not trusted.

EDIT: X-Frame-Options doesn't work at this time because ALLOW-FROM is not implemented in Chrome or Safari. I need to be able to support 3rd party domains.

Comment: There are much better ways. Use the `x-frame-options` header.

Comment: Would it be okay if you had the server check the Referer header, or maybe the Origin header, and set X-Frame-Options based on it?

Comment: @guest that is a good question. It's not clear to me if the Flash vulnerability extends to loading content in an iframe with a forged header.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's known that you can clear the Referer header and document.referrer, for example, by coming from a data URI. As long as you don't allow `undefined` document.referrer, this won't give attackers any unintended access.

You also declare in the question that Flash can make a request with an attacker-controlled Referer header. However, in this case, they won't be able to render the response as a document in your server's origin. They wouldn't be able to do any clickjacking attacks with that. Maybe CSRF though.

If the request is sent by an iframe, then the browser will send the correct referrer.

---

A minor issue with `document.referrer` is that you have to figure out what domain it is from the URL string. You'd have to be careful about how you do this.

Answer (score 3):

Yes. You can literally do:

```
document.referrer = "http://foobar.com";
```

If you only want to allow your site to be iframed on trusted sites, you use the `X-Frame-Options` HTTP response header.

[MDN Developer article for X-Frame-Options](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/X-Frame-Options)

Edit: If you need to make this work on browsers that don't fully support X-Frame-Options then you need something more complicated, whereby the 'outer' site communicates with the server hosting the iframed site to request a single-use token tied to the clients IP address, and use that to approve/deny access.

Comment: OK, but if I control the page that is being iframed, I'm not going to do that. X-Frame-Options support for other domains isn't implemented  in Chrome or Safari.

Comment: different threat model

Comment: @noah I've updated my post with a suggestion on how to do it without X-Frame-Options if the sites that are doing the embedding are ones you control.

Comment: I really don't understand how what you are saying applies to my situation. How would a malicious page overwrite the value of document.referrer within my iframe on a different domain?

Comment: re: edit, I've heard people say it's bad to tie authentication to a client's IP address. Why should one use it in this case?